# Is Photoshop forcing me to have a certain canvas size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm making a plate graphic for a new item at my company and the engineers have specified that they need it to be exactly 12.5 x 7.25 inches.

I set up my Photoshop file, specifying those dimensions, replicated their sketch and sent it over to them. They sent it back to me and told me if was the wrong size. Sure enough, Photoshop had made the canvas 12.5 x 7.377 instead of what I specified.

Luckily, I left extra padding at the top and bottom of the graphic, so I went to adjust the canvas size and just planned on letting Photoshop clip it a little.

[image: current size of my image]

[image: setting my canvas resize]

[image: approving the clipping error warning]

Photoshop took a minute to process the resize and then when it finished, the image moved up a little in my workspace. It didn't look different to me, but it's such a small change that I wasn't too worried.

However, when I checked the image size again, it's still 12.5 x 7.377.

I have been working on an artboard so I thought I could manually drag up the bottom of the artboard to resize it myself, but even that won't change the canvas/image height from 7.377.

I tried changing the image size (leaving it linked) by specifying 7.25 for the height and letting the width shrink below the specifications. (I planned on trying to pull back out the width afterwards.

Again, Photoshop processed the image resize but when I checked afterwards, it's still 12.5 x 7.377.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Will Photoshop not allow those dimensions for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its factory version it is **very unlikely** that Photoshop would behave this way. Setting a document size is the most basic thing you can do and I doubt someone at Adobe prohibited the use of your dimensions. This behaviour, if real, is probably due to some layer or guide in your document or maybe some obscure setting in your copy of PS.

Just to prove my point i am attaching a document i just made in my PS using your dimensions. Try resetting your preferences maybe, or rebuild a new document?

[image]

Comment: I made a new document and copied my work over and it seems to be the right size now. My preferences have never changed from default so I'm wondering if this is some kind of Photoshop CC 2017 bug. Thanks!